# How to display a return value from function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python

I am trying to get sensor value from a photocell and return the value to the web page. 
However since the sensor value changes very frequently, i try to just display the `lightstate` instead. However this does not work as well. How should i do it?

Here is my full script:http://pastebin.com/yKLt3mJN
And here is the python function:

```
@cherrypy.expose
def sensor(self):

    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO, time, os

    DEBUG = 1
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
    GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.OUT)

    def RCtime (RCpin):
        reading = 0
        GPIO.setup(RCpin, GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.output(RCpin, GPIO.LOW)
        time.sleep(1)

        GPIO.setup(RCpin, GPIO.IN)
        # This takes about 1 millisecond per loop cycle
        while (GPIO.input(RCpin) == GPIO.LOW):
            reading += 1
        return reading

    while True:
        sensorvalue= RCtime(12)

        if sensorvalue > 1000:
            print "switch on light"
            GPIO.output(11, True) #switch on
            lightstate ="On"
            time.sleep(1)
        else:
            print "switch off light"
            GPIO.output(11, False) #switch off
            lightstate ="Off"
            time.sleep(1)

        print sensorvalue # Read RC timing using BCM pin #18, physical pin 12

    return lightstate
```

Here is the HTML:

```
 <a id="photocell"; href="#">Sensor Controlled Lighting</a>
 <p id="photocellvalue"></p>
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
$('#photocell').click(function(){
                        $.post('/sensor').done(function (reply) {
                            $('#photocellvalue').empty().append(reply);});
                    });
```

Comment: how is `while` loop supposed to terminate? do not assign `lightstate` variable, simply return "On" or "Off" on those lines.

Comment: @Igor you mean something like this? ` if sensorvalue > 1000:
            print "switch on light"
            GPIO.output(11, True) #switch on
            return "On"
            time.sleep(1)`

Comment: yes, you don't need `time.sleep` because it is not going to be executed after `return`. I suspect that you are expecting that `sensor` will be sending multiple values back to the page. It will not.

Comment: So it will only execute the function once when I click on the `sensor controlled lighting`?

Comment: yes, that is correct. To have multiple calls to `sensor` you need to use `setInterval` javascript function.

Comment: If I use setInterval, can I display the sensor values?

Comment: of course, you can display whatever the server-side returns, see my answer

Answer (score 1):

This calls the server every second, and cancels the calls when clicked the second time:

```
var interval = null;
$('#photocell').click(function(){
  if (interval) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = null;
  } else {
    interval = setInterval(function() {
      $.post('/sensor').done(function (reply) {
        $('#photocellvalue').empty().append(reply);
      });
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work though :( now I can't even get a constant display of the value.